# Printing landscape documents with Java on duplex mode

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, duplex

I've a *JasperReports* report to be printed on landscape mode on a duplex printer. On this I've to support PCL5 and PCL6 printing drivers.

Searching on the internet, I discovered the following code snippet to do this job:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.OrientationRequested;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;

public class PrintingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //This are for configuration purpose
            String orientation = "LANDSCAPE";
            String duplexMode = "LONG_EDGE";

            int pageOrientation = 0;

            PrintRequestAttributeSet atr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            if ("Landscape".equals(orientation)) {

                atr.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
                pageOrientation = PageFormat.LANDSCAPE;

            } else if ("Reverse_Landscape".equals(orientation)) {

                atr.add(OrientationRequested.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                pageOrientation = PageFormat.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;

            } else {
                atr.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
                pageOrientation = PageFormat.PORTRAIT;
            }

            if ("LONG_EDGE".equals(duplexMode)) {
                atr.add(Sides.TWO_SIDED_LONG_EDGE);
            } else {
                atr.add(Sides.TWO_SIDED_SHORT_EDGE);
            }

            //Printing to the default printer
            PrintService printer = javax.print.PrintServiceLookup
                    .lookupDefaultPrintService();
            //Creating the printing job
            PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            printJob.setPrintService(printer);

            Book book = new Book();
            PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();

            pageFormat.setOrientation(pageOrientation);

            // Appending a exampledocument to the book
            book.append(new ExampleDocument(), pageFormat);

            // Appending another exampledocument to the book
            book.append(new ExampleDocument(), pageFormat);

            // Setting the Pageable to the printjob
            printJob.setPageable(book);

            try {
                // Here a could show the print dialog
                // printJob.printDialog(atr);

                // Here I pass the previous defined attributes
                printJob.print(atr);
            } catch (Exception PrintException) {
                PrintException.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static final int MARGIN_SIZE = 72;

    private static class ExampleDocument implements Printable {

        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(),
                    pageFormat.getImageableY());
            // Only on the first two documents...
            if (page <= 1) {
                // Prints using one inch margin
                g2d.drawString("Printing page " + page + " - duplex...",
                        MARGIN_SIZE, MARGIN_SIZE);
                return (PAGE_EXISTS);
            }

            return (NO_SUCH_PAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on **PCL6**, but, when tested on **PCL5**,  I noticed that LONG_EDGE and SHORT_EDGE rules are simple ignored. And that in both cases the job is sent as **LONG_EDGE**. This would not be a problem, except that *Java AWT* printing API resolves landscape printing by turning all pages 90º anti-clockwise causing the impression that it was printed on **SHORT_EDGE** mode.

Obs: I was able to print correctly with both configuration, **SHORT_EDGE** and **LONG_EDGE**, in portrait and in landscape, by using the *SWT API*. But I'm not able to convert the jasper printing request in a *SWT* compatible printing request.

My question is: has anybody ever confronted this situation? Which solution was given to it?

From my observation I've found these possible solutions:

1. Instead of letting the *AWT* turn the page and send a portrait print request, force it to send it as a landscape printing request;
2. Find a way to, when the page is in landscape mode, invert **LONG_EDGE** and **SHORT_EDGE** commands. Observe that for this one I would be obligated to correct the problem in which both are treated as **LONG_EDGE** requests.
3. Convert the *JasperReports* to use *SWT* printing *API*.

Comment: Why the PCL5 requirement?

Comment: As our project is migrating from Delphi platform to Java, we have to keep support to the features in the old version. We would like to avoid  adding PCL6 printer drivers as a requirement to ours Java version. Today we prepared the system to run the printing routine in `SWT`, for `PCL5`, or `AWT`, for `PCL6`, for _duplex landscape_ reports. The problem in `SWT` is that to print I need to handle report's pages in memory as images, wich is very heavy for some user stations.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it helps but I had this issue 6 years ago and the only solution was to use the printer's (Xerox) capability to receive the printing directives through an .xpf file. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xpif SYSTEM "xpif-v02012.dtd">
<xpif cpss-version="2.01" version="1.0" xml:lang="en">
<xpif-operation-attributes>
    <job-name syntax="name" xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">job name</job-name>
    <requesting-user-name syntax="name" xml:space="preserve">domain user</requesting-user-name>
    </xpif-operation-attributes>
    <job-template-attributes>
        <copies syntax="integer">1</copies>
        <finishings syntax="1setOf">
        <value syntax="enum">3</value>
    </finishings>
    <job-recipient-name syntax="name" xml:lang="en-US" xml:space="preserve">domain user</job-recipient-name>
    <job-save-disposition syntax="collection">
        <save-disposition syntax="keyword">none</save-disposition>
    </job-save-disposition>
    <media-col syntax="collection">
        <media-type syntax="keyword">stationery</media-type>
        <media-hole-count syntax="integer">0</media-hole-count>
        <media-color syntax="keyword">blue</media-color>
        <media-size syntax="collection">
            <x-dimension syntax="integer">21000</x-dimension>
            <y-dimension syntax="integer">29700</y-dimension>
        </media-size>
    </media-col>
    <orientation-requested syntax="enum">3</orientation-requested>
    <sheet-collate syntax="keyword">collated</sheet-collate>
    <sides syntax="keyword">one-sided</sides>
    <x-side1-image-shift syntax="integer">0</x-side1-image-shift>
    <y-side1-image-shift syntax="integer">0</y-side1-image-shift>
</job-template-attributes>
</xpif>
```

which was sent to the printer along with the file needed to be printed.